# How can i fix my (complicated) query so that it gives me proper table?

Tags: mysql, sql, math, subquery

So i have this query:

```
SELECT a.year, a.avg_kw_price, b.avg_kw_consumed
From (select year, avg(value) as avg_kw_price 
 from AP_DATA where substring(series_id, 8) ='72610' 
 group by year)a, 
(select substring(YYYYMM,1,4) as year, Value*9506632 as avg_kw_consumed 
from RESIDENTIAL_EN_CONSUMPTION where MSN = 'ESRCBUS' and  
substring(YYYYMM, 4,2) = '13' 
group by substring(YYYYMM,1,4)) b
WHERE a.year = b.year;
```

My two tables look like this: AP_DATA: (the 72610 part refers to item kw/h)

```
series_id           year    period      value
APU000072610        1996    M11        0.092              
APU000072610        1996    M12        0.092              
APU000072610        1997    M01        0.092              
APU000072610        1997    M02        0.092              
APU000072610        1997    M03        0.093              
APU000072610        1997    M04        0.092
```

Table RESIDENTIAL_EN_CONSUMPTION looks like this (the 13 at the end of a YYYYMM item refers to the total for that year):

```
MSN      YYYYMM     Value    Description    Unit
ESRCBUS  201008      200     Electricity    Trillion btu
ESRCBUS  201112      396     Electricity    Trillion btu
ESRCBUS  201113      1200    Electricity    Trillion btu
ESRCBUS  201213      2000    Electricity    Trillion btu
```

What I want my table to look like is basically something like this:

```
year     avg_kw_price      avg_kw_consumed
2011     1.2                 158049
2012     0.9                 120310
```

As of right now I'm getting an empty table with the query im using.  Also, as you can see I multiply Value by 9506632 because i did some math and thats how you go from trillion btu per year to kw/hour. However this is not that important and im not sure if its right so if i must i will take it out and keep in btu.  How can I fix my query so that it actually gives me a table that i wanted, if you want, disregard the unit conversion?

Comment: Your years don't match.  Fix the data so you have matching years in both tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the tables i included i just made up the dates, unfortunately in the real tables i have thousands of records and the dates are set up differently (in the way i showed) in the tables, also both tables have different number of years.

Comment: Look at the table for each subquery. See if they look as expected.

Comment: @MvG OMG i just realized my substring for YYYYMM in the second subquery is wrong! its supposed to be substring(YYYYMM,5,2) not 4,2 !!!
it works perfectly now!!! haha awesome

Comment: @coderasd: I guess I'd have written this as ‘YYYYMM like "%13"’ in any case, but that's just me being lazy. DO you want to answer your own question, or delete it instead?

Comment: @MvG guess ill just answer it since deleting questions counts negatively towards your account. Thanks for the tip on %12, had i done that from the start i would not have encountered my problem.

Comment: @MvG `% 13` wouldn't work. `YYYY * 100 + MM % 13 ~ YYYY * 9 + MM % 13`, not `MM` in the general case. `% 100` gives the right result though.

Comment: @Cimbali: I'm talking about `%` as a wildcard for the string matching operator `LIKE`, which has nothing to do with the modulo operator. Of course, modulo would be an option as well, and perhaps even the better option, but further from what OP wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A strategy I frequently use is: create temporary tables with the pieces of the data you need, create the appropriate indexes on them, and then put all together (in other words: a *divide-and-conquer* strategy).

So, let's see what can be done:

```
-- Your subquery "a":
drop table if exists temp_step01;
create temporary table temp_step01
    select year, avg(value) as avg_kw_price 
    from AP_DATA 
    where substring(series_id, 8) ='72610' 
    group by year;
alter table temp_step01
    add index idx_year(year);
-- Your subquery "b":
-- I'll split the process in two, to ease things a bit
drop table if exists temp_step02;
create temporary table temp_step02
    select cast(substring(YYYYMM,1,4) as unsigned int) as year -- It's easier to 
                                                               -- handle numbers
         , Value*9506632 as avg_kw_consumed 
    from RESIDENTIAL_EN_CONSUMPTION 
    where MSN = 'ESRCBUS';
alter table temp_step02
    add index idx_year(year);
drop table if exists temp_step03;
create temporary table temp_step03
    select year
         , avg_kw_consumed -- I think you should aggregate this value somehow
    from temp_step02
    group by year;
-- Finally:
select a.year, avg_kw_price, avg_kw_consumed
from temp_step01 as a
     inner join temp_step03 as b on a.year = b.year
```

You should check that all calculations are correct, but I think the idea is clear:

1. Filter the data from the first table and put it in a temporary table.

   Add all the appropriate indexes to this table.
2. Filter the data from the second table and put it in another temp table.

   Add all the appropriate indexes to this table.
3. Do whatever calculations you need to do. If needed, use additional temp tables.

   I insist: Add all the appropriate indexes to this table.
4. Pull all the data you need in a last, simple, query.

Use the temp tables to perform all the "heavy-lifting" tasks: filtering, aggregating, etcetera. The key is to perform the steps separatedly, and put them all together at the end, using the indexed fields of each one to optimize the appropriate joins.

Remember: temporary tables are only visible to the connection that creates them, and are dropped once the connection is closed or killed.

Answer (score 0):

Realized i had my second substring written incorrectly. It should've been substring(YYYYMM,5,2) not substring(YYYYMM4,2). Sometimes its the little things. I'll leave this open in case it might be useful to anyone else.

Comment: How could it be useful?